# admin-sdk: users/list works, but members/list doesn't?

Tags: php, api, google-groups, google-admin-sdk

Within my company's domain, I'm able to successfully search for users via this call:
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list
(domain: mydomain.com, viewType: domain_public, and my own email as the sub= in the service account authorization.)

I've confirmed that with a web browser, anyone in my company can view membership of any group in the company by going to https://groups.google.com/a/mycompany/forum/#!members/mygroup.

It seems to follow (same api, obviously open company-wide) that I should be able to obtain group members via this call:
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/members/list

However, even using the API Explorer, I'm getting:

```
403 OK
- SHOW HEADERS -
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "forbidden",
    "message": "Not Authorized to access this resource/api"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Not Authorized to access this resource/api"
 }
}
```

This doesn't seem to make sense... Is this a permission that needs to be/can be changed at the organization level? (ie my admins have allowed user/list but haven't yet allowed members/list?)

If this is somehow intentional behavior within the API... why?  And has anyone found a way around?  (Screenscraping https://groups.google.com/a/mycompany/forum/#!members/mygroup would probably work, but just seems so insane when there's theoretically an API...)

FWIW - I'm trying to use php to do this in a service running on a linux machine, but until I can get it working within even the API explorer, I'm not sure that's relevant.  My first attempt was to take all the code that works for users/list and make the call to members/list instead.  When that failed, I tried API Explorer and failed there as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the admins to allow the "Read" Admin API Privilege for users in your domain.

Admin Console > Admin Roles > Create new role (e.g. "All users GroupsAPIRead") > Privileges > Admin API Privileges (not Admin Console API Privileges) > Groups > tick "Read" (don't tick create, update or delete).

Comment: Excellent - I'll make that request today!  Thank you Peter!

Answer (score 0):

The domain_public option for users.list() was added recently to allow end users to retrieve a limited view of the directory. Currently there is no groups equivalent. To run groups.list() you need to be a delegated admin with rights to read groups.

Comment: Is there a "best" way to request domain_public be added to groups.list() as well?  (Do we know what brought about the domain_public being added to users.list()?)  In the meantime, I'm going to have to try rolling my own via screenscraping... that just seems so wrong!